# a column(variable) in a data frame is also 'data.frame',how to change it into int or numeric?

Tags: r

'str(data)' to browse the data frame and found one variable is a 'data.frame', how can I change it into a normal vector/variable? Because now it cannot be exported correctly.

```
str(data) 
$ ID        : num [1:3177] 1.11e+11 1.11e+11 1.11e+11 1.11e+11 
$ indcate   :'data.frame':  3177 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ X: int [1:3177] 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 1 1 ...
```

(1)so I tried to change the type of this variable but failed

```
> as.numeric((data$indcate))
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> as.integer((data$indcate))
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
> as.factor((data$indcate))
 X 
<NA> 
Levels: c(2, 3, 1)
Warning message:
In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

(2)here is the export file, I export it as csv.file. There are some redundant columns behind.
[image]

Comment: It might be better to fix the process that created this nested frame, can you provide context?

Comment: There is only so much we can help without a proper example. Please share your data with `dput(data)`, or `dput(head(data, 10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I've totally understood but I think the issue is that your item is currently a list.  You should be able to resolve it by adding `unlist()` to your code:

```
> as.numeric(unlist(indicfactor$indcate))
```

Comment: thanks for your help,sincerely.it may because the var ’indcate' is created by fuc ‘data1$indcate<-discretize(data1$indincome,"equalfreq",nbins);and indcate is a ’data.frame‘ stored in data1.